# Windows 8.1 / Windows 10 breaks my ASP.NET / IIS : "Service unavailable"

Tags: url-rewrite-module, windows-8.1

With Windows 8.1 finally released to MSDN/Technet today I came across the following issue running my ASP.NET application after doing an in place upgrade with Win 8.1 RTM:

> **Service Unavailable**
>
> HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

- The AppPool has died and shows a status of `Stopped`
- The IIS log has nothing
- There's a clue is in the Windows Application log which contains this error

  `The Module DLL C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\rewrite.dll failed to load.  The data is the error.`

How can I recover my IIS to make it work again?

Comment: The `System` Event Log shows an error related to the one in the `Application` log: `A listener channel for protocol 'http' in worker process '####' serving application pool 'MyAppPool' reported a listener channel failure.  The data field contains the error number.` @Simon_Weaver has the correct answer.

Comment: It's worth noting that this also happens when upgrading from Win 7 to Win 10. @simon-weaver 's own answer is still correct :)

Comment: and ALSO from Win 10 to Win 10 Anniversary edition. ugh

Answer (score 127):

It looks like a simple uninstall and re-install of the rewrite module will do the trick.

**Edit:** As others have said - try a repair first - if it works then that should be faster.

It doesn't look like the [Microsoft Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) is able to uninstall it so just go to `Programs and Features` to uninstall it.

You'll find it listed as `IIS URL Rewrite Module 2` and just click the `Uninstall` button on top.

Then reinstall it from here:

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Make sure your App Pool is started - or just restart IIS and it should all work again.

---

*Edit*: 8/30/16 : A similar but unrelated error can occur if you have the 'new' .NET core installed and update to Win 10 Anniversary edition. See here: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1583 - Running a repair on VS 2015 Tooling Preview should fix it. Wanted to add it here since the errors are very similar to this answer.

Comment: I realize Windows 8.1 has a new IIS 8.5, but if anyone knows specifically why this fails I'd be interested to know. This is pretty much the only extension I am aware that I'm using so I don't know if this is specific to the rewrite module or any modules.

Comment: @blake you got this error specifically when upgrading to Windows 8.1? I've had it before when I did a new install of Windows and just forgotten to install this module. I assume since IIS 8.5 is a new version it just wipes everything out including extensions (or modules or whatever this is). Fortunately nothing else seems off in my upgrade and all my other IIS settings were retained

Comment: Yes, I did an upgrade to 8.1 that whipped out all my apps :\.

Comment: I'm running Windows 8.1 When I uninstalled the module my app actually started working.

Comment: You can verify in the Event Log: you will see `The Module DLL C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\rewrite.dll failed to load.  The data is the error.`

Comment: Uninstaller was unavailable, had to manually delete this registry key

    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IIS Extensions\URL Rewrite

Comment: Uninstalling and reinstalling URL Rewrite worked for me as well on **Windows 10**.  Not sure _why_ tho...

Comment: I just install latest version of IIS URL Rewrite Module 2. Don't need to uninstall anything.

Comment: Upgrading from Win 8.1 to Win 10 caused this issue for me, and reinstalling solved it. Thing I noted on the WPI is that URL Rewrite, though it's still v2.0, has a newer release date of 5/27/2015. Perhaps for some reason this is why there was a compatibility issue, @Simon_Weaver.

Comment: This error suddenly happened to me overnight on an otherwise perfectly working Windows 10 machine, and this fix worked perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 53):

I got this Event Log error after updating Win8.1 to Win10. To fix, go to the **Control Panel -> Programs and Features**, locate **IIS URL Rewrite Module 2**, right click and select **Repair** (it's quick). Next, restart your stopped AppPool(s). Should be OK now.

No need to uninstall nor reinstall.

Gary Davis

Comment: I just got this on upgrading to Windows 10 and this worked for me.

Comment: Upgrading from Windows 2008 -> 2008 R2 (don't ask, didn't want to), same problem, same solution.

Comment: I just had the same issue after a regular Windows Update (so strange). This solution fixed it for me.

Answer (score 26):

Don't need to uninstall. Just do a Repair instead, and it will works.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, though this didn't work for me. The uninstall/re-install method did work for me though.

Comment: Simple repair worked for me.  This was after a Windows Update, in case someone is wondering.

Answer (score 13):

For some weird reasons, the only solution for me was to install previous version of the module, from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7435

Comment: for Windows Server 2012 r2 out of the box for demo/test - this was the trick that worked. rewrite 2.1 simply would not work

Comment: This did the trick for me. No reinstall, no repair but simply a downgrade to 2.0 with the link you provided. Good job!

Comment: Does anyone have the installer for rewrite 2.0 version? The direct link provided by @kevin is already broken..

Answer (score 3):

I just ran in to this issue after an update. All of the app pools where stopped! 
Starting them resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with similar issues last night.

It started out with a complaint about missing redirect.dll. After installing IIS' Redirect feature, that log message disappeared and all I was left with was a bunch of error messages from WAS. It tried starting my application pool five times until giving up.

> A listener channel for protocol 'http' in worker process '120' serving
>   application pool 'my app pool' reported a listener channel failure. 
>   The data field contains the error number.

The error code was "8007007E" (File not found according to google).

I then installed ProcMon from [sysinternals.com](http://sysinternals.com/) and every time the w3wp process complained about "NAME NOT FOUND" right before terminating, I googled and installed the corresponding IIS feature. I repeated this until I had installed them all and got everything working again.

Installing everything is not a good solution, but I do not have time to investigate deeper right now.

Comment: I took the lead from your answer and ticked "HTTP Redirection" under Common HTTP Features. That fixed it. I also had enabled asp.net 3.5 and the 3.5 .net extensibility but I think it's the redirection one that did it. This was after windows must have uninstalled IIS for me and it's been a pain to set it all up again.

Answer (score 1):

I came across similar symptoms after changing my domain password.  I had to also reset my password in my (hard coded!) App Pool settings on my dev box.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with "httpplatformhandler.dll failed to load". Again the solution was to download the appropriate httpplatformhandler install msi from http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/httpplatformhandler and then run a repair.

Answer (score 0):

The Repair worked for me after updating to W10 Insider Preview 160826-1902

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem in Windows Server 2012 R2. After I update Windows Updates to newest, it works.