# Url rewrite 2.1 stops Application pool in IIS 8.5 (return 503 status), windows server 2012R2

Tags: url-rewrite-module, iis-8.5, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I install the URL Rewrite from the Web Platform Installer.
No added rule.
Then, when I access website url, it returned 503 code and Application Pool was stopped.
It works normally when I uninstall the URL rewrite module from Control Panel.

I have tried many searches on google but no results.

I found that in Event log:
- The Module DLL C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\rewrite.dll failed to load. The data is the error. Application pool 'DefaultAppPool' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool.
(rewrite.dll is exits)

Any ideas?

Comment: What did you see from Windows event log? If there is any process crashed, edit your question to include the exact info from log entries.

Comment: @LexLi, thanks for suggest.
I found that: Application pool 'DefaultAppPool' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool.

Comment: There should be other entries to match "a series of failures". This one alone is useless.

Comment: The Module DLL C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\rewrite.dll failed to load.  The data is the error.

Comment: Sounds like Microsoft ships a broken package again. Open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com and ask them to fix.

Comment: @LexLi I found UrlRw version 2.0 and it's working good for now.

Comment: @GinCanhViet where did you find that version 2.0?

Comment: @CraigEddy I found it on google. "Urlrewrite 2.0 download"

Comment: @LexLi One of my client also met this problem. They are using Windows Server 2012 R2 x64 Simplified Chinese. When I installed the latest version of URL Rewrite Module 2.1, then the application pool will crash. ( `The Module DLL C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\rewrite.dll failed to load. The data is the error.`)  When I switch to 32-bit enabled for this application pool, then it works. It's kinda weird.

Comment: Try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18714709/windows-8-1-windows-10-breaks-my-asp-net-iis-service-unavailable

Answer (score 1):

In event log I found the same message. I.e. The Module DLL C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\rewrite.dll failed to load. The data is the error.

For me the solution that worked was to replace the "rewrite.dll". In 2 of our other server it was working fine and they were installed in 2017. So I just copied the "rewrite.dll" from that server and replace it on my new server.

For me the older version(v7.1.1952.0) of the dll works, but new version ( v7.1.1993.2351), which comes with the latest setup, doesn't work.

BTW you need to stop the IIS before you replace the dll and start again.

Comment: Hi @joseph, i also face the similar scenario like you. the version the I installed was v7.1.1993.2351. I dont have any other version of the rewrite.dll module. Do you have any idea where can I download another version of that rewrite.dll ? It has been almost more than 3 weeks I'm struggling to fix the issue since the server that i used doesnt have any internet connection other than connection to another database server only.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience and nothing I did fixed the issue e.g. repair, reinstall, restart, etc.

Then I removed what the Web Platform Installer installed and manually installed the **x64** version of URL Rewrite and everything now works nicely.

Make sure what you’re installing matches the OS.