# HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable. App pool stops on accessing website

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7, localhost

There are number of posts on this and I have tried many a things by now. But to no avail. Myself a Winforms Developer basically, started working on this Web stuff few days back as my company is taking Web initiatives.

I have a ASP.Net project and I want to host it on local IIS. In `Project properties -> Web` settings I chose `Use Local IIS Server` and gave a url as `localhost/MyApp`. I tried accessing it on my firefox browser and received error as `HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.`

Previously I got many other errors and I one by one fixed them all. But struck with this one. These are the settings I have in my project

1. Application Pool set to ASP.Net v4.0 Classic
2. App Pool `Enable 32 bit Application` property is true
3. App Pool is started
4. Project build property set to `Any CPU` for Target framework

But I would like to mention a weird behavior. Following is something that I am facing

1. Application Pool is Started
2. I try to access my local website (by giving url as `localhost/MyApp`)
3. I receive the error as `HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable`
4. Application Pool is Stopped

I have seen [following link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322937/iis-http-error-503-the-service-is-unavailable) and I have already tried it. For the above behavior I reached [here](http://forums.iis.net/t/1183845.aspx). According to this link, Computer name should not have `.` in it. I don't have any `.` in my Computer name but do have `-` in it. Also my domain name contains `.` in it. Moreover I can't change these settings as its my office laptop and our TFS settings are bound to our Domain and Computer Names.

Can anyone help me to understand whats happening? Please guide me. Thanks.

**Edit**

I have following code in `Global.asax`. `Application_BeginRequest` method is empty in same file.

```
protected override void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    base.Application_Start(sender, e);
    String _path = String.Concat(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath, ";",
                                         System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH"));
    System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", _path, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
    MyAppLog.Initialize();
    MyAppLog.WriteMessage("Application Started");
}
```

**Update**

As per the suggestions in Comment, I am able to run the website from Cassini.

Comment: Do you have any code in your Global.asax which runs on application start? Anything which might be getting stuck in a loop? You enabled `Enable 32 bit Application` but are you using any 32-bit only DLLs?

Comment: What happens when you run it in Cassini?

Comment: @RGraham: I have project build property set to `Any CPU`. So I think used dlls should not be a problem. Please see the edit for Global.asax code. Thanks

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: No idea of whats Cassini is. I downloaded it now from http://cassinidev.codeplex.com/. I can see some dlls and exe in downloaded files. Could you please help me how to use it? Meanwhile I will try to read on this issue from internet sources.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: I am able to run website from Cassini.

Comment: check the substatus codes in the iis web log
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943891

Answer (score 382, accepted):

One possible reason this might happen is that the Application Pool in IIS is configured to run under some custom account and this account either doesn't exist or a wrong password has been provided, or the password has been changed. Look at the advanced properties of the Application Pool in IIS for which account it uses.

Also the Event Log might contain more information as to why the Application Pool is stopping immediately on the first request.

[image]

Comment: In my case, this was the issue. I had changed my Windows password and my local IIS for Windows 8.1 stopped working. I had to update each project in multiple places. In IIS 8, I had to update the credentials in the application pool by right clicking on the pool and clicking "Advanced settings -> Process Model -> Identity". I then had to update the Site itself by going to "Sites -> MySITE -> Advanced Settings -> Physical Path Credentials"

Comment: Even if the account exists and the password is correct, it may have been disabled; this would cause the same symptoms.

Comment: Yes, That's the solution. My account password is changed very often. And I forgot to give the new password in the "Advanced settings"

Comment: checking Event Log is the way to go, always helped me in these issues, last time i checked the event log and i found that it is a fail in loading the rewrite.dll in iis, I went to programs and features in control panel, repaired the installation, and everything went back normal.

Comment: We had a recent password change. This was the solution. For others, see screenshot here: https://i.imgur.com/rp8bnGy.png

Comment: In my case application is working width Application Pool Identity with load user profile = true, and stoping 2 days later itself. I have changed it to the local service, i think it will corrected. But i dont know and couldnt understand why! ? :)

Comment: For the braindead like me, it might be worth adding steps 1-7 in bullets. But then I'm braindead. Did I mention that?

Comment: In my case my user was recently migrated from one domain to another, hence I faced this error.

Comment: my issue was the expired password but after I adjusted it I continued to have the problem.  I then changed the identity back to the built-in choice of AppPoolIdentity, started the site and then changed it back to the user that had the expired password.  It is working now

Comment: It does not make any sense on IIS 7 or higher. Anyone with password changed certanly will know taht and set credentials with the new generate one. Therefore this anwser is obsolete.

Answer (score 63):

Ok, I have another solution for one specific case: if you use WINDOWS 10, and you updated it recently (with Anniversary Update package) you need to follow the steps below:

1. Check your `Windows Event Viewer` - press Win+R and type: `eventvwr`, then press ENTER.
2. On the left side of `Windows Event Viewer` click on `Windows Logs` -> `Application`.
3. Now you need to find some ERRORS for source `IIS-W3SVC-WP` in middle window.
4. Probably you will see message like:

> The Module DLL >>path-to-DLL<< failed to load.  The data is the error.

5. You have to go to `Control Panel` -> `Program and Features` and depending on which dll cannot be load you need to repair another module:

   - for `rewrite.dll` - find **IIS URL Rewrite Module 2** and click `Change`->`Repair`
   - for `aspnetcore.dll` - find **Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.0 - VS 2015 Tooling ...** and click `Change`->`Repair`.
6. Restart your computer.

Comment: This answer helped me troubleshoot a similar problem.  "Service Unavailable" error fixed by removing Core 2.2 (repair alone did not fix). up vote.

Comment: great answer, the log show me The Module DLL C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\compdyn.dll failed to load.  The data is the error. so I install Dynamic Content Compression

Comment: For me, it was: `The Module DLL C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\iis_ssi.dll failed to load. The data is the error.` So I installed Select Server Side Includes per [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37474915/503-error-caused-by-iis-ssi-dll-failed-to-load-in-the-event-viewer-eventlog)

Comment: The accepted answer did not help me either, but this one did, however, I only uninstalled the IIS URL Rewrite Module 2 and it worked...I did not repair it or reinstall it.

Answer (score 16):

For my situation is that my login password changed, while the application pool still uses the old one. So just click the "Advanced Settings" of your application pool and reset your "Identity".

Comment: I would agree that this happens quite often

Answer (score 12):

I was facing the same problem, and debugged it using the event logs. First it said that : "The description for Event ID 5059 from source Microsoft-Windows-WAS cannot be found".

I then turned on WAS using [turn windows features on/off](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee323462%28v=office.13%29.aspx). Then i saw this in eventvwr
"Microsoft-Windows-DistributedCOM cannot be found".

Finally I gave up and deleted the App Pool (that used to stop on accessing the website) and created it again, as it is. This resolved the problem.

Comment: And if you happen to have a bunch of sites referencing the same app pool, you can use [appcmd](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe#HowToUse) to [batch-update](http://blogs.iis.net/ksingla/things-you-can-do-by-piping-appcmd-commands) them:  `appcmd list site /xml | appcmd set site /[path='/'].applicationPool:YOURNEWPOOL /in`

Comment: Worked for me too.  By upgrading from 2008 to 2012, the app pools were not entirely happy.

Answer (score 10):

Most of Time, it was occured due to AppPool Setting.

Check the following to resolve this

1. Check Apppool service is running.
2. Check Identity of AppPool.
3. Enter the new password if it has changed for that identity.

The following Images show these setting in IIS

[image]

Answer (score 7):

For anyone coming here with Windows 10 and after updating them to Anniversary update, please check this link, it helped me:

https://orcharddojo.net/blog/troubleshooting-iis-apppool-crashes-status-503-after-windows-10-anniversary-update

In case link goes down:
If your Event log shows that aspnetcore.dll, rewrite.dll (most often, but could be others as well) failed to load, you have to repair the missing items.

Here are two specific issues we've experienced so far and how to fix them, but you may bump into completely different ones:

```
"C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\rewrite.dll" (reference)
    Go to "Programs and Features" (Win+X, F) and repair "IIS URL Rewrite Module 2".
"C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\aspnetcore.dll" (reference)
    Go to "Programs and Features" (Win+X, F) and repair "Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.0 - VS 2015 Tooling ...".
```

Answer (score 6):

If you have McAfee HIPS and if you see the following error in event viewer application log:

> The Module DLL C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\HipIISEngineStub.dll failed to load.
>       The data is the error.

Then the following resolved the issue in my case:
https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB72677&actp=LIST

Quote from the page:

> 1. Click Start, Run, type explorer and click OK.
> 2. Navigate to: %windir%\system32\inetsrv\config
> 3. Open the file applicationHost.config as Administrator for editing in Notepad.
> 4. Edit the <globalModules> section and remove the following line:
>      
>    <add name="MfeEngine" image="%windir%\System32\inetsrv\HipIISEngineStub.dll" />
> 5. Edit the <modules> section and remove the following line:
>      
>    <add name="MfeEngine" />
> 6. After you have finished editing the applicationHost.config file, save the file, then restart the IIS server using iisreset or by restarting the system.

Answer (score 6):

In my case I checked event logs and found error was 
Cannot read configuration file ' trying to read configuration data from file '\\?\', line number '0'.  The data field contains the error code.

The error code was 2307.

I deleted all files in C:\inetpub\temp\appPools and restarted the iis. It fixed the issue.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue. I solved it by adding my user to the "Log on as a batch job" policy under "Local Security Policy" > "Local Policies" > "User Rights Assignment".

Answer (score 5):

When I first time add the service and created the app pool for it.
I did "iisreset" from command prompt, and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

I was experiencing this error and in my case the cause was that some time ago I modified the user password, and the 503 error didn't appears till I restarted the application pool.

So I fixed it setting the new password on Applications Pools / Advanced Settings / Identity / [...] / Set... / Password / Confirm Password

Answer (score 4):

If you can run the website in Visual Studio debugger, then might be able to see where in your code the application pool is crashing.  In my case, it was a function being called recursively an unlimited number of times, and that caused a stack overflow.  Note: the Windows event log and the IIS logs were not helpful to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue with iis 8.5. After searching the eventViewer under windows Logs-->applications, I realized that I'm having a permission error for the machine.config file of the .net framework located at "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config".
Giving it a permission for IIS_IUSRS solved my problem (right click the file-->properties-->security-->edit-->add-->IIS_IUSRS)

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to these `Anniversary Update` issues (thanks Microsoft) if the file you are missing is `cgi.dll`, ie your `Event Viewer` has

```
The Module DLL C:\WINDOWS\System32\inetsrv\cgi.dll failed to load.  The data is the error.
```

Then to fix this:

1. Go to `IIS Manager`
2. Select the very top row in the `Connections` panel (typically your PC name)
3. At the very bottom of the right panel, under `Management`, you should have `Web Platform Installer`
4. Once that loads, select `Products`
5. In the search type in `cgi` then hit `<Enter>`
6. Select `IIS: CGI` then click `Add` on the right and finally `Install` on the bottom
7. After installing it should force you to restart your PC and you should be fixed.

Comment: Mine was the "Url Rewrite" that I uninstalled and then reinstalled. Because i got this error: "The Module DLL C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\rewrite.dll failed to load.  The data is the error."

Comment: I wonder why CGI is required. I guess I have to dig into this. I excluded it from my config as I wanted to harden my IIS.

Comment: This worked for me as well, but first I had to actually install the Web Platform Installer, which is located on the right-side of the panel, after doing that 'Web Platform Installer' showed up where you said it would.

Answer (score 4):

To Fix the problem, Follow the steps as I faced the same issue and below solution worked for me

1. Give full Rights or at least read access rights of Folder "C:\inetpub\temp" to IIS_IUSRS
2. also check same rights given to User IIS_IUSRS of folder "C:\inetpub\wwwroot".

hope this solution works!

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, all my app pools were stopping whenever a web request was made to them. Although I was getting the following error in the Event Viewer:

> The worker process for application pool 'appPoolName' encountered an
>   error 'Configuration file is not well-formed XML ' trying to read
>   configuration data from file
>   '\?\C:\inetpub\temp\apppools\appPoolName\appPoolName.config', line
>   number '3'.  The data field contains the error code.

Which told me that there were errors in the application.config at:

> C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config

In my scenario, I edited the web.config on deploy with an element IIS clearly dislikes, the applicationHost.config scraped the web.config and inserted this bad element and wouldn't resolve until I manually removed it

Comment: "an element IIS clearly dislikes" whats that specific element you have mentioned ??

Comment: I made this post over 4 years ago. I am not sure what element was in the web.config but that is not the point. The app pool problem that the OP describes was happening to me and I was getting back these unhelpful error messages. The cause of the above was that I had put an incorrect entry into my site's web.config. (maybe with a spelling mistake or syntax error or section that IIS didn't recognise to be valid)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the steps outlined at [this link from Orhan's answer](https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB72677&actp=LIST), you may need to additionally remove the native module by going to IIS Manager > Server Root > Modules > Configure Native Modules. Select MfeEngine and then select Remove.

Answer (score 3):

Changing "Managed Pipeline Mode" from "Classic" to "Integrated" worked for me.
It can be changed at Application Pools -> Basic Settings

Comment: This fixed my issue which appeared after applying the following windows KB to our windows server 2008 R2 runing IIS 7.5.

###
2019-07 Security and Quality Rollup for .NET Framework 3.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6, 4.6.1, 4.6.2, 4.7, 4.7.1, 4.7.2, 4.8 for Windows 7 and Server 2008 R2 for x64 (KB4507420)

More information: 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/4507420

###

Answer (score 3):

I'm late to the party, but the solution that worked for me isn't listed.

The solution for me was simply to **delete the web site and application pool within IIS, and re-create them**.

This is because originally I had create the site/folder first, then installed the dotnet core runtime.  For some reason this failed to allow the site to start up.

Once re-created, the site came to life with none of the other suggestions being required.

Comment: Sadly, for a .NET 7 ASP.NET Core Web API project, this was the only thing that helped for me, too. Thanks for the idea! ♥️

Answer (score 2):

One possible reason this might happen is that you don't have enough disk space in your server machine. You can find more information in event viewer.
if such thing happen, just stop the IIS, clean some free disk space and restart the IIS and then start the App Poll. [image]

Answer (score 2):

Such 503 errors were encountered on our side on Windows Server 2019 while setting up a fresh new Classic ASP website.

In fact, in the App Pool, setting "**.NET CLR Version**" to "**No Managed code**" caused the App Pool to stops 2 seconds after being started, thus generating WAS 5002 and 5021 errors in the Windows Event Log.

The solution was to put "**v4.0**", even if no .NET is used.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the web sites displayed "503 Service unavailable" and the application event log showed "...\aspnetcorev2.dll failed to load. The data is the error." This only happened for IIS sites where where the IIS setting "Enable 32-Bit Applications" was **True**. The system was stopping the app pools for these sites, which is what generated the "503 Service unavailable" message when trying to retrieve the site.

It turns out the path specified in this application event log didn't even exist. Trying to repair the two "Microsoft.NET Core SDK 2.1.50x" versions installed on the system didn't resolve the issue, nor did installing the latest and only aspnetcorev2.dll that Microsoft seems to have available, nor did uninstalling these SDKs.

NOTE: Microsoft doesn't even seem to have the installers available anymore for the original v2 ASP.NET Core versions that had been installed on my system.

**What worked:**
Since I don't have any ASP.NET Core sites on this system, the solution that worked for me was to uninstall all the related DLLs from my system and to remove them from the IIS applicationhost.config file by commenting them out (see [aspnetcore.dll failed to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40161982/aspnetcore-dll-failed-to-load) and [applicationhost.config file path in IIS 7, 7.5, 8, 8.5 and IIS 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28701647/applicationhost-config-file-path-in-iis-7-7-5-8-8-5-and-iis-10)). If you do use a later version of ASP.NET Core, I'd think you could just as well update the references in applicationhost.config [I haven't tried that].

Answer (score 1):

Check the log written to [event viewer\Windows Logs\System] node.
Source is 'WAS'.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case this application pool automatically stopped due to error log folder I created in local which is not exist in server. Check the web.config file whether any key path you added which is exist in server or not.

Answer (score 0):

**Will this answer Help you?** 
If you are receiving the following message in the EventViewer

> The Module DLL aspnetcorev2.dll failed to load. The data is the error.

**Then yes this will solve your problem**

---

To check your event Viewer

1. press Win+R and type: `eventvwr`, then press ENTER.
2. On the left side of `Windows Event Viewer` click on `Windows Logs` -> `Application`.
3. Now you need to find some ERRORS for source `IIS-W3SVC-WP` in the middle window.

---

if you receiving the previous message error then solution is :

**Install Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable 86x AND 64X (both of them)**

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54455428/4390133)

Answer (score 0):

In my case error message displaed in Windows Event Viewer -> Windows Logs -> Application was **"The Module DLL C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\rewrite.dll failed to load. The data is the error."**
Uninstalling rewrite module via installer solved the problem. I wasn't using any rewrite rules so I uninstalled  rewrite module. Reinstalling  the module may help the problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue on some legacy servers running Windows 2008 R2. 32bit applications would crash the app pool and return a 503 without hitting the app code. The problem seems to be related to .net core module erroneously trying to load the 64bit version of the module even though the 32bit application in question was **not** a .net core app.

It seems that IIS still loads the module when figuring out which module to load to service the request and trying to load a 64bit version into a 32bit process is no bueno.

In the end, I had to uninstall all versions of .net core from the server and reinstall the latest (at this time 3.1.15- we're not using 5 yet). After that my 32bit apps and .net core apps could coexist on the same server.

This is the blog post that helped me resolve this after days of banging my head on it. Hopefully it helps someone out.
[Blog post with the solution](https://vdachev.net/2016/08/25/aspnetcore-dll-failed-to-load/)

Answer (score 0):

Give full Rights rights to Folder "C:\inetpub"
Work for me!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Environment.Exit(0) command caused the problem.
It may help someone so shared.

Answer (score 0):

If you work for a company, maybe the reason is changed Active Directory password(Your domain account password). Companies request you to change your AD password periodically. To resolve this issue, it is enough to update passwords belong to application pool and website identity