# What is the file location of applicationhost.config in the different versions of IIS?

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-express, iis-8, iis-10

What is the exact file path of the `applicationhost.config` file in the different versions of IIS, for example: IIS 7, 7.5, 8, 8.5 and 10?

Comment: If anyone is looking for their **machine.config**, powershell can tell you for your active environment `[Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment]::SystemConfigurationFile` note if the result has *Framework64* in the path if you're looking for the 64bit config

Answer (score 131, accepted):

For the "big" IIS versions since IIS 7, the location is always the same:

```
 %windir%\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
```

For IIS Express there is one per user, the default location is:

```
%USERPROFILE%\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config
```

again it's the same for all versions.

You can run multiple instances of IIS Express per user, you would need to specify the location of the `applicationhost.config` as the command line parameter `/config` for `iisexpress.exe`

Comment: The part for IIS Express is not 100% correct. IIS Express command line interface allows a config file to be loaded from anywhere. The default one is primarily used by Visual Studio.

Comment: @LexLi `The default one is primarily used by Visual Studio` where is that located??

Comment: @hr-tis - The default one for IIS Express is the second location mentioned in the answer.

Comment: If you start a web app directly from Visual Studio (2017) the file used is:

`[SOLUTION ROOT FOLDER]\.vs\config\applicationhost.config`

Tip: If you right-click the IIS Express icon in taskbar and select Show All Applications, you can click on each site to see the paths used.

Comment: update on SaveHansson's comment: In Visual Studio 2019, `[SOLUTION ROOT FOLDER]\.vs\config\[SOLUTION NAME]\applicationhost.config]` (the SOLUTION NAME part is new).

Comment: Mine was at, [SOLUTION ROOT FOLDER]\.vs\[SOLUTION NAME]\config\applicationhost.config (slightly different order)

Answer (score 1):

You can delete one or more site in `IIS server 7` or above using the application host `config` file which resides under the `"windows/system32/inetsrv/config"` folder.

If you want more detailed information then you can read this blog post 
[Delete or manage one or more IIS websites through application host configuration file](http://evrytn.blogspot.com/2020/04/how-to-delete-all-websites-hosted-in.html)