# Could not run WCF debug mode in visual studio 2017 community version

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2017

When I try to run WCF debug mode in Visual studio 2017, I get the following errors in events viewer :

> The Module DLL 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\Asp.Net Core
>   Module\V2\aspnetcorev2.dll' could not be loaded due to a configuration
>   problem. The current configuration only supports loading images built
>   for a x86 processor architecture. The data field contains the error
>   number. To learn more about this issue, including how to
>   troubleshooting this kind of processor architecture mismatch error,
>   see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=29349.

And by that I couldn't launch my service.

Comment: Doesn't seems to be WCF problem but issue asp.net core v2. Some corrupted file is stopping IIS Express to open. Try reinstalling asp.net core v2.

Comment: Did you find your answer?

Comment: I had tried reinstalling asp.net core v2, but it's still not worth :((. Thanks

Comment: If you are not using .net core , you could try to remove reference to .net core.[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40161982/aspnetcore-dll-failed-to-load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40161982/aspnetcore-dll-failed-to-load),please don't forget to backup the applicationhost.config

Answer (score 0):

Thank for all of your suggestion. I had done to resolve this by add comment 2 line of the file ".vs\config\applicationhost.config"

```
<!--  <add name="AspNetCoreModule" image="%IIS_BIN%\aspnetcore.dll" />
            <add name="AspNetCoreModuleV2" image="%IIS_BIN%\Asp.Net Core Module\V2\aspnetcorev2.dll" /> -->
```