# Application pool stopped automatically in IIS 7

Tags: iis, application-pool

I have a 64 bit server. I have changed the application pool to enable the 32 bit DLLs ("enable 32 bit DLL"). After I reset IIS and check it gives this error:

> Error : "503 Service Unavailable".

I checked in IIS and found that the application pool is automatically stopped.

Answer (score 5):

You typically get 503 Service unavailable when the application pool fails 5 times in less than 5 minutes. It could happen if your credentials for the service account isn't correct.

Try using a different credentials (or use Network Service/Local System) just for testing purpose. If it still doesn't work, take a look at your Event logs and share the results.

Comment: Amazing.  I've been trying to figure this out for weeks.  I came across this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19652709/http-error-503-the-service-is-unavailable-app-pool-stops-on-accessing-website), but none of the answers helped.  Using your answer, I made my app pool fail five times within just a minute and, sure enough, 503 code.  Now I can apply a fix to the problem

Comment: On IIS 10 only once will make the app pool stopping so 503 will raise.

Answer (score 2):

In my case `Application pool user profile` is corrupted, so windows create new temporary profile for that.

If you have `C:\Users\TEMP.IIS APPPOOL` folder in your machine then `Application pool user profile` is corrupted.

Below step working for me:

- Find all registry folder have `.bak` extension in below given registry path

  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`
- Now check that registry folder have key is `ProfileImagePath` and value is `C:\Users\TEMP.IIS APPPOOL`
- Go to https://web.archive.org/web/20150906110036/https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/947215 link and follow step given for correct corrupted user profile.

Comment: your link is broken.

Comment: I have updated web.archive.org link.