# 503 error, caused by `iis_ssi.dll failed to load` in the Event Viewer (eventlog)

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012

I'm getting this error in the event log (EventViewer):

```
The Module DLL C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\iis_ssi.dll failed to load. The data is the error.
```

OS is Windows2012 Server. How to fix it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to add SSI in Server Manger. Follow these steps:

1. Add Roles and Features
2. In Server Roles, expand Web Server (IIS)
3. Expand Application Development
4. Select Server Side Includes

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 2012r2 Operating systems, to be more precise following this step:

1. Open Server Manager Dashboard
2. Click on Add Roles and Features
3. Expand Web Server IIS (if not already selected)
4. Expand Web Server
5. Expand Application Development and ensure that all unchecked boxes are selected.
6. Click Next on the select feature windows to advance
7. In the Confirm installation selection select specify an alternate source path for the installation CD such as F:\sources\sxs to complete the installation.