# Blank page when I run or debug MVC application in local machine

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working in MVC 5 application, and all was working well. but after time of edits and updates, I get a blank page when I try to run or debug it in my local machine.

the blank page come if I working under local IIS or IIS Express or VS development server, all return a blank page.

The response header of the request is `503 Service Unavailable`

Comment: Have you seen this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322937/iis-http-error-503-the-service-is-unavailable)?

Comment: thanks @Jasen. Yes, I checked it, but seems it is not as my problem. due to I get the same problem with IIS Express & VS dev server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solved:**

I find the `app_offline.htm` file in the directory of my application which cause this behavior...

just write for who may get this later, I don't know how/when this file come there.

Comment: Aaaaaaaah! Thank you very, very much. I was trying to fix this for 3h or more. Finally...

Answer (score 0):

It may be because the application pool that contains your application is in stopped status. Restart the app pool for your application in IIS as in screenshot below.

[image]