# HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable when port 80 is already free

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, iis-7

Before you go and suggest it as a duplicate of other `IIS HTTP Error 503` questions, I have already tried many solutions available on SO and also on Google but the problem is not resolved. Below are the most popular solutions that I have found:

[IIS - HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322937/iis-http-error-503-the-service-is-unavailable)

[Solve HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable in IIS](http://www.brainbrushups.com/2013/07/solve-http-error-503-service-is.html)

**In my case:**

`IIS` is not working while the port 80 is open and free to use.

[image]

As far as I know the error is caused if the application pool is not enabled (started) for the website in `IIS`.

I have already closed all other applications like Skype, Google Disk etc who can possibly use port 80 and checks if the port is in use or not.

[image]

Then I looked into the Application Pools of IIS and found `DefaultAppPool` status `stopped`.

[image]

After starting the `DefaultAppPool` I recheck my web and gets the same error.

And now the situation is like, `DefaultAppPool` status shows `started` until I don't hit any URL. Whenever I request any URL for my local websites or localhost, the browsers returns me the **Service Unavailable** error message and the `DefaultAppPool` status change to stopped automatically.

I have already tried the `iisreset` command but after resetting `IIS` the problem is still there.

Comment: Basicly error 503 means that somthing is wrong in your code or in your web server. I would sugest the you'll try to change your website application pool to the asp.net 4 app pool (the second one in the list). I had the exact problem after installing framework 4.5. After moveing the application to the asp.net v4 it solved.

Comment: @Tomer Klein I have already change the Application pool to Asp.net 4 app pool but still same error and also created a custom app pool as test but the browser returns the same error.

Comment: Bytheway it gives the same either I access my deployed websites or simple localhost to check if the IIS is running or not.

Comment: So what event log shows?

Comment: Have you try looking in the windiws event viewer under application/system log?

Comment: @TomerKlein **Error** Application pool DefaultAppPool has been disabled. Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) encountered a failure when it started a worker process to serve the application pool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably identity under which you are running your app pool i.e. administrator has wrong password or disabled. Try changing this identity to something like network service or local service or any other valid identity.

Answer (score 8):

There is an uncommon cause for 503 error. To fix this, follow these easy steps:

Run this command

```
netsh http show urlacl
```

It will list all reserved urls, find the url with relevant port.

```
 Reserved URL            : http://+:80/
    User: NT SERVICE\Machine
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;S-1-5-21-2127521184-1604012920-1887927527-67210)
```

Then delete the entry with this command (replace the url part with yours):

```
netsh http delete urlacl http://+:80/
```

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webtopics/2010/02/17/a-not-so-common-root-cause-for-503-service-unavailable/

Comment: Worked for me too (with a listener of a gps server).