# HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable in IIS

Tags: .net, iis

I have look through a few answers on SO for a solution to this. I have tried everything on the question page [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322937/iis-http-error-503-the-service-is-unavailable) but to no avail. Once I change the user to something else, it will work and show the page, but my web-app is unable to make a connection to the database as any other user is unauthorised to access the DB in my dev-environment.

I have tried copying the settings from another person on the dev-team who it works for but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you changed your password to log on to your computer recently?

Comment: Have you restarted the computer since you changed the password?

Comment: Just today for windows updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try logging into IIS and change your **Identity** to your user account but with your new password that you use to login. You will need to do this everything you change your login password.

The reason it was working before is because it was running with your old credentials but not your new ones, which took effect on the restarting of your computer.

**Note**

I think the link you provided, the first answer actually says this, but does not make reference to the user login password being changed affecting the Identity in the IIS. Might just be the wording.

Comment: Tried putting the credentials with the newer password and it worked fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

IIS:

1. Did you install ASP.NET 4 run-time component? Check in "windows
   Components > IIS".
2. Check frameworks (installed .Net 4) in "windows
   Components > IIS"

SQL:

1. Check you connection string, Named and Default instances of SQL.
2. Check permission to access SQL from network (SQL Server configuration Manager)
3. Check you Firewall Settings.

Comment: The DB is fine as it is on a shared server for the team to access the information. They are all currently able to connect, so I believe it is a IIS problem.