# Url rewrite does not install on windows 10 IIS 10

Tags: windows, iis, url-rewriting, iis-10

I need the Url Rewrite module on my IIS But it does not install and says that I need at least IIS7

Comment: A new version of this phenomenon is that Web Platform Installer says that unfortunately, the module could not be installed, but doesn't give any indication of what went wrong.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Because it took me hours to find the problem, I am posting this solution to my own answer so it will save someone else this work.

In short you have to change the major version of the IIS via the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\MajorVersion` to 9 during installation and then back to 10 afterwards.

Solution is from: https://forums.iis.net/t/1223556.aspx
[image]

Comment: This does not change anything, but https://stackoverflow.com/a/38262403/2279059 works.

Comment: Sounds unwise to me.  Safer to just install the 2.1 version for Windows 10.

Comment: i could not change the version no in registry. it show me error alert saying: "Cannot edit major version, Error writing the value's new content"

Answer (score 108):

the newer version supports win10 out of the box:
https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Comment: I like this solution more, you can just install it on Windows 10 without changing the Registry.

Comment: 100% better solution, worked for me - I am not chaging my registry!

Comment: My question is why does the microsoft docs redirect us to useless MSI file download page instead of this one? Crazy...!! Btw thanks @Pelister for saving my time.

Comment: At the time of this comment, the above link goes to version 2.0, but version 2.1 has been released. This page appears to be more recent and non-version-specific: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Comment: link in the answer is not valid anymore. The one provided by @Chris in comments worked for me.

Comment: @Chris: Why in the world doesn't Web Platform Installer give me that version, but rather offers version 2.0 that then cannot be installed?!

Comment: @O.R.Mapper that is not my area of expertise and I have had problems with it in the past. But I can offer a guess... do you have the latest version of Web PI? There is a 5.0 at https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx and a 5.1 at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/web-platform-installer/web-platform-installer-direct-downloads

Comment: I took the liberty to edit the answer to a correct link

Answer (score 31):

I found the downloads at the bottom for 2.1 work without any registry hacks:
https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

I would prefer this as an option you can select from the roles, but who knows...

Comment: perfect, instead of changing version number

Comment: This works for me. Thanks.  Originally I thought it is in the control panel turn windows feature on and off, but it is not there.  One needs to go to separate site to download it.

Answer (score 4):

**Issue:** For me the [link](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) provide, failed to install URl Rewrite 2.1 on windows server 2016, IIS 10.0

**Fix:** Instead of this i have followed below steps which works perfectly.

- Download [Microsoft URL Rewrite Module 2.0 for IIS (x64)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47337)
- Follow the steps mentioned in [Setting up an HTTP/HTTPS redirect in IIS](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9953/38/setting-up-an-httphttps-redirect-in-iis)

Comment: the download link is broken, correct one (2.1) for newer IIS is https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite - the 2.0 one doesn't install

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis: This answerer explicitly said version 2.1 could not be installed for them. Maybe their environment is somewhat different from yours, where only version 2.1 works?

Comment: anyway their 2.0 link (at fix paragraph) doesn't download anymore. I had issue with installing 2.1 via platform installer, but the one I posted did work. There's a chance MS fixed something in that download (could be a newer build number with better metadata for the installation) since the original post

Answer (score 3):

Additionally, entering your username and password in the "Specific user: " field found in Default Web Site --> Right click Virtual Database Folder --> Advanced settings --> Physical Path Credentials --> **Specific user:** helped me like in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322937/iis-http-error-503-the-service-is-unavailable) that helped me as well. The top answer after following these directions from this forum and the original forum provided in the hyperlink helped me get my *local host directory* to work.

Comment: The install instructions say to run msiexec /I rewrite_2.0_rtw_x64.msi from command prompt as administrator. For my system I had to run msiexec /I rewrite_amd64.msi as admin. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47337

Answer (score 1):

Link: [Microsoft URL Rewrite Module 2.0 for IIS (x64)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47337)

After installing it you will notice a new icon in IIS for URL Rewrite:
[image]

and you will be able to use *rewrite* tag in your web.config

Answer (score 1):

In case, after installing [IIS URL Rewrite 2.1](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite), **URL Rewrite** option is still not visible at **IIS Manager**, check Jalpa Panchal's answer [URL Rewrite not visible in IIS10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63504011/url-rewrite-not-visible-in-iis10).

Answer (score 1):

Use **Web Platform Installer** in IIS.
Find for "**URL Rewrite**". 
When installation window appears, in the bottom of it find the link "**Options**".
In "Change Options" window find "**Which Web Server would you like to use?**" and select the right version. In my case it's "**IIS**".
If you don't have such option and install it from the link https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite
Then restart IIS service. In my case worked **IISRESET** command in **CMD** with **Admin rights**.
Works like a charm!
[image: IIS Screenshot. URL Rewrite installation.]

Answer (score -1):

Anyone still struggling when trying to open the executable file. I had to open the CMD in the downloaded files location and run `MSIExec /i rewrite_amd64_en-US.msi`

Obviously using your appropriate file name