# How to 301 redirect all .asp pages to .php pages on IIS with web.config

Tags: php, iis, asp-classic, http-status-code-301

as a php programmer, I usually redirect pages with .htaccess, but having inherited a project formerly made with asp, I need to redirect pages to same-named pages in php. For pages that do not exist in php, index.php should be the redirected page.

Would you please help me with some suggestions and resources? I can only find single page to single page redirect.

Thank you very much

Comment: Use the [Url Rewrite Module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38262403/692942).

Comment: Thanks. The IIS is remote and I cannot install anything on the hosting machine. Or can I just download on a regular Windows machine, execute it and get the resulting file to be then uploaded on the remote server?

Comment: No, but presumably the remote IIS host will have it installed so all you need to do is configure the rewrite rule in your sites `web.config` file.

Comment: But that's what I was asking at first, as I am not into asp. I don't know hiw the web.config has to be built

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IIS URL Rewrite and Web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410067/iis-url-rewrite-and-web-config)

Answer (score 1):

First you have to configure the .Net handlers to process your Classic ASP requests
You do that with runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" read more [here](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/oct/25/caveats-with-the-runallmanagedmodulesforallrequests-in-iis-78#runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests=%22false%22----different-than-you-might-think!) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048863/modules-runallmanagedmodulesforallrequests-true-meaning)

Next, you can use the built in URL rewrite module to do a wild card replace or a one-to-one map via web.config

As a backup, you can use the Global.asax's Application_BeginRequest event to parse out the requested URL and do a permanent redirect to PHP

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you ullfindsmit, that's beyond my knowledge. I am using the web.config with some regex lines to rewrite the url from ?q=v&q1=v1 to /v/v1/ form, but still cannot redirect all .asp pages to .php relative ones. I would be happy even to redirect all the .asp pages to index.php. This is what I am using, but wih no succes: 

    <rule name="DynamicRewrite" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="(.*)" />
     <conditions>
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.asp" matchType="IsFile" />
     </conditions>
     <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php" />
    </rule>

Comment: There Are two things at play here, the first one is making.net handle all your ASP pages, the next is the rewrite . To make ASP.net handle ask request use the run for all m a managed requests setting, next is to do the actual mapping

Comment: How do I instruct the server to the "run for all managed requests"?

Comment: I have inserted this line of code in the web.config **<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">** but I do not understand how to map the .asp to be redirected all to index.php. Can you please help me? Thank you

Comment: this is a two step process. Step 1, make .net handle .asp file requests via the runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" Step 2 build your redirect rules. To do a simple test, redirect all .asp to php based on the rule here >> https://forums.iis.net/t/1233447.aspx