# URL Rewrite not visible in IIS10

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I installed URL Rewrite 2.1 by using rewrite_amd64_en-US.msi. Installation went smooth, but I am not able see the URL rewrite icon in IIS. My system is IIS 10 in Windows Server 2016.

I am installing using command `msiexec /a rewrite_amd64_en-US.msi /qf /L*V re.log` in admin command prompt

Also there is no entry for URL Rewrite in Control Panel, nor rewrite.dll file in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv.

The last few lines of installation log is

```
MSI (c) (C8:90) [15:38:38:027]: Note: 1: 1707 
MSI (c) (C8:90) [15:38:38:027]: Product: IIS URL Rewrite Module 2 -- Installation completed successfully.

MSI (c) (C8:90) [15:38:38:027]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: IIS URL Rewrite Module 2. Product Version: 7.2.1993. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation. Installation success or error status: 0.

MSI (c) (C8:90) [15:38:38:027]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (C8:90) [15:38:38:027]: Cleaning up uninstalled install packages, if any exist
MSI (c) (C8:90) [15:38:38:027]: MainEngineThread is returning 0
=== Verbose logging stopped: 8/20/2020  15:38:38 ===
```

Another point to note is my server doesn't have Web Platform Installer. When I try to install that, I am facing similar issue - no errors while installing, but icon not visible in IIS.

Please guide me in troubleshooting this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are invoking **msiexec.exe** command using **Elevated Privileges**.

To do so, you need to:

1. Click **Start** or press **Windows-Key**;
2. In the search box, type **CMD**;
3. Right-click **CMD** and select **Run as Administrator**. For further details, check https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/e/elevated.htm or https://winaero.com/how-to-open-elevated-command-prompt-in-windows-10/;
4. On the new **Command Console**, run MSI package installation command

   `msiexec.exe /i rewrite_amd64_en-US.msi /l*v C:\msilog.txt /qf`

   or

   `msiexec.exe /i "rewrite_amd64_en-US.msi" /L*V "C:\package.log"`

Comment: Thanks, this worked. As there was no Run as Administrator option for msi, I opened the command prompt as admin and executed the msiexec with /a switch, which is for admin. But it didn't work. Based on your answer, I changed from /a to /i and it worked smoothly. Not sure why I got the successfully installed message in log with /a.