# How to troubleshoot a 503 error in IIS

Tags: windows, iis

I deploy ISS on my location machine. And when I hit my browser with http://localhost/ab, I get a 503 error.

And then I go to iss manager, and i do see a site 'ab' under my machine name. And in 'Directory' under 'Logging', I see directories 'W3SVC1' 'W3SVC2', 'W3SVC3', and i go the most recent log, I don't see any 503 error.

My question is how can I debug my issue?

I read [HTTP Error 503, the service is unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322937/iis-http-error-503-the-service-is-unavailable)

And I don't see any error under " Event Viewer, either under the System or the Web Server (IIS)."

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

503 should be coming from http.sys you need to check in HTTP err logs for the exact reason.

You can find HTTP err log files here  - C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR
Search for the site you are trying to browse in the logs and the last but one field will give you reason.

Based on that you can troubleshoot as explained here

https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/820729