# MVC4: Application pool keeps stopping

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

What are the reason for the application pool to be stopped? I am asking about stopping the application, not recycling.

Does reaching private byte memory limit is one of them? When I debugged my website, it seems that the application pool is keep getting recycled at every minute, then suddenly the application pool is stopped and giving me

> Error 503 unavailable.

I found out that actually my hosting provider degraded my private byte memory limit from 500MB into 100MB and without telling me. My application has minimum requirements of 150MB-200MB private bytes limit.

I am here asking this to make sure that the problem was because the memory limit, not the other thing.

Comment: Can you check if there is any error in event log for this?

Comment: Not necessarily, i have no access, it is hosted externally

Comment: Exact duplicate of [HTTP Error 503, the service is unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322937/http-error-503-the-service-is-unavailable)

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the user identity is outdated, especially if you've tried starting a stopped app pool and the next request again fails.

In IIS, go to the Application Pools under the Server, then find the correct Application Pool for your web site, and click on it. On the Advanced Settings menu to the right, select Identity and change it and enter new user and password. Click on your Application Pool again, and select Recycle to restart it.

You can also try looking at the error message in Event Viewer, under Windows Logs, Application, Details tab.

Taken from [HTTP Error 503, the service is unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19682985/2422013).

Comment: The problem is that I have no access, it is hosted externally. It works fine in my local IIS. I have asked the support guy, I found out that the hosting server degraded my private byte memory limit from 500MB into 100MB. My website will reach 150MB at start. So I am here to make sure that the cause of the application pool stopping was because the private byte memory issue.

Comment: Please don't copy answers verbatim from other questions. Instead, please flag as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue and I couldn't find anything in the event log location that MD GHOUSE mentioned. I ended up finding a warning in Event Viewer --> Windows Logs --> System that stated that the identity in my application pool did not have batch logon rights. I am adding that user to the AD group to resolve. I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

try going into the IIS and selecting the application pool that is stopping. Click on advanced settings and go down to identity. Change the item from Application pool to Local Service. Restart the application pool or IIS and problem should be solved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, its due to domain password reset. When I created the application pool, I've used my old password. But after I reset my password, then application pool was getting stopped until I go and use my new password in the application pool advanced settings.