# Unable to Start Debugging on the Web Server on Windows 7

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to setup some web applications to run locally on IIS 7.  I have gone through everything on

https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(vs.debug.error.http);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5)&rd=true

Many other posts mention also doing

```
aspnet__regiis.exe -i
```

Which I have done several times.

In the IIS manager I can see my site, I can start the app pool find (as well as recycle and stop), but whenever I go to `localhost` I get a 503.  If I try to run the debugger the app pool just dies.  One site mentioned that having Visual Studio installed first can cause problems so I uninstalled that and re-installed but that was ineffective (it's also installed/uninstalled through a company web store so I don't know how "clean" it gets after the install).

I've tried manually creating the site, etc in IIS Manager still with no results

Under the Add or Remove Windows Features in Programs I have enabled everything under IIS as well so everything should be installed

Comment: Can you get a one-page "Hello world" website working?

Comment: Every site I have tried (including a one-pager) has returned 503 and not been able to attach debuggers

Comment: Does a simple HTML page work? I would ignore debugging of ASP.NET until you can get a website working. The Windows logs in Event Viewer might help. Also, [HTTP Error 503, the service is unavailable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13322937/1115360) and the other pages under "Related" in the column on the right of this page.