# problems setting localhost

Tags: iis, localhost

I have windows 10 and I want to run some local web site tests.  To do this, I need to set up IIS.  I follow the steps outlined here https://www.howtogeek.com/112455/how-to-install-iis-8-on-windows-8/ and I get this result :

[image]

But in FIrefox, when I type localhost, the error says:

Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at localhost.

```
The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

In chrome, the error says:

This site can’t be reached

localhost refused to connect.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

In edge the error says:

Hmm, we can't reach this page.
Try this
Make sure you’ve got the right web address: http://localhost
Refresh the page
Search for what you want

It also says on a different machine with Edge:

**Service Unavailable
HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.**

And in IE, the error is an internet search on localhost.

Please advise.

I found this web site:
https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/jul/05/windows-10-upgrade-and-iis-503-errors

and this one
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webtopics/2010/02/17/a-not-so-common-root-cause-for-503-service-unavailable/

and this one
[HTTP Error 503, the service is unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322937/http-error-503-the-service-is-unavailable)

First of all, I noticed "Reason 1: The HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable occurs if the Application Pool of the corresponding Wep Application is Stopped or Disabled or Paused. or The given user Identity of Application Pool may be invalid due to expired password or locked."

And linked to this: http://www.morgantechspace.com/2013/12/HTTP-Error-503-The-service-is-unavailable.html

I tried the steps outlined in http://www.morgantechspace.com/2013/12/HTTP-Error-503-The-service-is-unavailable.html There are two different lists of steps.  The first one failed to fix the problem and the second list of steps failed because I don't know how to generate a new identity.

The original poster on the other stack overflow page, I see, gave up.

[image]

Here is the event viewer this should help solve this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

My experience with setting up websites in IIS and getting server errors is that it is most probably a misconfiguration with the application pool.  What programming language is the website written in?

You can try changing the .NET CLR Version in the application pool, and try changing it from Integrated to Classic (or vice-versa) managed pipeline mode and see if that helps. You can also try going into the advanced settings tab of the application pool and try enabling 32-Bit applications.

I would also add a new url to my hosts file that allows you to use something other than http://localhost to connect to the website, especially if you are setting up more than one website.