# HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable while hosting VB.Net application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis-7, iis-8

I'm getting an error like this after hosting application in IIS 10. But its worked fine in locally. I have tried many ways, but still getting these error.

Comment: please read [ask] and explain what you tried exactly so far

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the Answer posted here: [HTTP Error 503, the service is unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322937/http-error-503-the-service-is-unavailable)

> It could be that the user identity is outdated, especially if you've
>   tried starting a stopped app pool and the next request again fails.
>
> In IIS, go to the Application Pools under the Server, then find the
>   correct Application Pool for your web site, and click on it. On the
>   Advanced Settings menu to the right, select Identity and change it and
>   enter new user and password. Click on your Application Pool again, and
>   select Recycle to restart it.
>
> You can also try looking at the error message in Event Viewer, under
>   Windows Logs, Application, Details tab.
>
> Edit: jcolebrand 2017-05-04
>
> I had this error, and it was because I was doing some powershell
>   scripting, so I had C:\path instead of C:\path. Yay typos! Saying
>   this to say, always double check your keyed-in values.

Answer (score 0):

You can get 503 error for many reasons and this is question is open ended.You have to get more details.Some basic steps can be like this

1.Check whether your application pool is stopped
 2.Check Windows event log both System And Application (Look for event from WAS or IIS related)
e.g.
[image: iis error]
 3.Check any crash (again above step can help