# Cannot read configuration file ' trying to read configuration data from file '\\?\<EMPTY>', line number '0'

Tags: iis, windows-10

An app pool kept stopping every time it was started and gave this error in the application logs:

> The worker process for application pool 'APP_POOL_NAME' encountered an
>   error 'Cannot read configuration file ' trying to read configuration
>   data from file '\\?\<EMPTY>', line number '0'. The data field contains
>   the error code.

Several users have noted this occurs after the *Windows 10* Fall Update.

Comment: Please consider  to improve the question - i.e. explaining what your setup and what you believe would help other users to identify their have same problem (i.e. mentioning that "IIS worked fine and start failing after Fall Creators update" if that is the case for your machine would make this question easier to use by future visitors). Side note: This question is selected as review audit and discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359828/bad-close-votes-review-audit/359832#359832).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to review this question. I can't see the discussion as it appears to be deleted. I have taken your advice and edited this question, based on the comments to my answer.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

If you recently installed the Windows 10 Fall Creators Update, this problem and a solution for it may be covered in [this Microsoft knowledge base article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4050891/error-http-503-and-was-event-5189-from-web-applications-on-windows-10). The solution:

- Open an Administrator Command Prompt (**not** a Powershell prompt)
- Run: `net stop WAS /y`
- Run: `rmdir /s /q C:\inetpub\temp\appPools`
- Run: `net start W3SVC`

Thanks to @weir for [reporting this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/issues/572).

---

This wasn't a permission error in this instance, but it's would be well worth ensuring `IIS_IUSRS` has access to your site config just in case. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615296/cannot-read-configuration-file-due-to-insufficient-permissions)
for steps on how to do this.

This issue appeared to be a virtual directory appeared in the IIS temp files, which was pointing to the wrong place. To fix:

1. Go to the drive your IIS is installed on, eg. `C:\inetpub\temp\appPools\`
2. Delete the directory (or virtual directory) with the same name as your app pool.
3. Recycle/Start your app pool again.

Comment: Amazing! I have no idea how you figured this one out, but I ran into the same problem after installing .Net Framework v4.7.1 and this fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for figuring this out! It seems to have been a result of the Fall Creators update.

Comment: I have reported this bug to Microsoft by creating the following issue on the dotnet GitHub repo: [After installing 4.7.1, IIS AppPool stops with "Cannot read configuration file"](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/issues/572).

Comment: @BradBamford - Did you install .NET Framework 4.7.1 separately or as part of the Fall Creators Update?

Comment: @weir As I pointed out in the GitHub issue, .NET 4.7.1 was a red herring. The issue occurs due to a bug in Windows update logic that we have since fixed. If you happened to update to Windows 10 Fall Creators update before the fix, you'd run into this issue. I'm going to leave a [link to the KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4050891/error-http-503-and-was-event-5189-from-web-applications-on-windows-10) here in case anyone else encounters this issue.

Comment: Nice one. I've updated the answer to reflect this fix.

Comment: Just FYI, I still got issue even though I got the creators update after 1/1/2018, so it doesn't appear to be fixed in distribution.

Comment: This helped me so much. Your reputation score should go further up @StePammenter :-)

Comment: I installed the Win10 Fall Creators Update on 2018-04-02 and encountered this issue, so it is **definitely** far from "fixed".

Answer (score 2):

I have deleted the `DefaultAppPool`, then I have created a new pool `MyAppPool` and added applications in there and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to add that this can also manifest if the drive the config file is located on is full.  We just found that out today and freeing up space and restarting the application pool fixed it.

Comment: Remember: when a drive is full, you will see a lot of weird messages everywhere, except "Your disk is full" :D

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the file `C:\inetpub\temp\appPools\DefaultAppPool\DefaultAppPool.config` got corrupted, and I just could not delete it through all possible means. Then, I just created a new App Pool and moved the application to the new app pool to make it work. Thanks to all the great answers posted here!

Answer (score 1):

Hey in my case it was the naming of my website.
It was setup as ($webiste$...) with a couple of dots at the end.

After renaming it worked right

Answer (score 0):

### Check for trailing spaces in the app pool name

In our case, it was because the name of the application pool had a trailing space.

I changed the application pool to a fresh one with no trailing space, and everything worked fine. Later, when our deployment tool pushed a new update to the site/app, it was back to using the application pool with the trailing space, and the error returned.

Once we fixed the deployment process to no longer have the trailing space in the name of the application pool, all worked as expected.