# IIS 10.0 AppPool crashing (causing 503 error)

Tags: asp.net, windows-10, iis-10

**Situation**
After the latest Windows 10 updates (Nov 2017) were installed, the Application Pool required by a local web application keeps stopping/crashing displaying the message below in Event Viewer:

> The worker process for application pool 'SrvAppPoolv4.0'
>   encountered an error 'Cannot read configuration file ' trying to read
>   configuration data from file '\\?\<EMPTY>', line number '0'.  The data
>   field contains the error code.

**Setup**
Windows 10
Internet Information Services (Version 10.0.16299.15)

**What I've tried**
I've tried a few things that I've found via Google, both here on Stackoverflow and other sites, nothing has helped so far. Some of what I've tried:

- Changed the AppPool Identity to a different user (Right-click, Advanced Settings).
- Checked the permissions on the `machine.config` (all four of them in the various `\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\..` and `..\Framework64\..` folders).
- Unchecked the IIS and .NET features (Control Panel / Windows Features) and then added them back in again.
- Uninstalled the application in question, cleared everything, then re-installed it.

Nothing has helped.

Besides reinstalling the entire machine, what else can I try?

Also, besides the Event Viewer, are there any other logs I can review to get more details? I read something about an application log, but nothing as to where to find it?

Update:
I just tried what user3739842 suggested Add/Remove Programs, selecting IIS Express and then `Repair` - issue remains.

**Solution**
For me the solution was the following (thanks rusware):

1. Go to the drive your IIS is installed on, eg. `C:\inetpub\temp\appPools\`
2. Delete the directory (or virtual directory) with the same name as your app pool.
3. Recycle/Start your app pool again.

In my case, it was a virtual directory which was corrupted.

Comment: I had an issue after the update using iis express and localhost, I went to add/remove programs and selected 'repair' for iis and it resolved itself. may be worth a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi the answer to your problem can be found here. It worked for me and same error

[Cannot read configuration file ' trying to read configuration data from file '\\?\<EMPTY>', line number '0'.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47309480/cannot-read-configuration-file-trying-to-read-configuration-data-from-file)