# IIS 10.0 AppPool crashing

Tags: iis, windows-10, asp.net-core-2.0, web-hosting

After a company forced Windows 10 update today, the Application Pool required by a local web application keeps stopping/crashing displaying the message

> Service Unavailable
>   HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

I have checked the the below similar posts and followed the solutions provided with no luck.

[#1 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47338226/iis-10-0-apppool-crashing-causing-503-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47338226/iis-10-0-apppool-crashing-causing-503-error)

> For hosting .Net Core applications in IIS, .Net CLR Version of
>   application pool should be No Managed Code as shown in below
>   screenshot.

[#2 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50244861/iis-10-app-pool-keeps-stopping-due-to-aspnetcore-dll-failed-to-load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50244861/iis-10-app-pool-keeps-stopping-due-to-aspnetcore-dll-failed-to-load)

> Go to the drive your IIS is installed on, eg. C:\inetpub\temp\appPools\
>   Delete the directory (or virtual directory) with the same name as your app pool.
>   Recycle/Start your app pool again.

I have also followed the Microsoft instructions.  Made sure to first follow the steps in  "Turn Windows features on/off) and then installing the ASP.NET Core hosting bundle as instructed.

[#3 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x)

I'm not having any luck.

Here's my setup App Pool
[image]

Here's my setup Site
[image]

I've done everything I know.  Does anyone have this same experience and can share a solution?

As always, a big thank you to the experts out there!

**UPDATE**: 
I created a new AppPool with Identity "ApplicationPoolIdentity" setting.  The page will run however I need to connect to a SQL Server instance with my own credentials because we use Windows authentication on most of the pages.  When I create a new AppPool with my credentials it will not stay running.

Comment: Ask your AD administrators to create a service account for you to test out the connectivity. Normal user accounts are the least you should try. If you do want to know the root cause, it would be pretty tough to collect crash dumps and analyze them.

Comment: I had a similar issue but it only affects application pool hosting .Net Core with .Net CLR Version of application pool as "No Managed Code". Turns out it's the newly installed docker. Simply uninstalling docker solved my problem.

Comment: @kakusan How do I find out if this is installed on my machine?  Not even sure what it is or does.

Comment: My situation might be different from yours. It worked before and stop working only after I installed docker. If you didn't install docker, most likely it's different issue. Anyway, to [test your docker installation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/), simply open a terminal window and run docker --version.