# Can't start IIS 10 Express

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, iis, iis-express

I can't start IIS Express 10 with .NET Core since yesterday. Nothing changed outside of a NET Framework 3.5 and 4.8 Update.

I tried restarting Machine, restarting VS, reinstalling IIS Express, the port is not occupied by any other process. In fact when I change the port the app is running on I still get the error, I get the error no matter the port I use. I removed the .vs folders and IIS Express folders. I also reset the network adapters and started shutting down applications one by one (which anyway actually didn't make sense because no matter which port I change it to, the error stays as mentioned.)

The error that I am getting when I check the logs:

```
Failed to register URL "http://localhost:50721/" for site "Application" application "/". Error description: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (0x80070020)
```

I checked the other posts and nothing works, I am using VS2019.

Any idea?

Comment: Can look in the project properties then Debug and see if the ports for http and https happend to be the same? Do you have set multiple projects to start?

Comment: We don't use SSL so there is just one port definition

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27985816/403671

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this error means binding conflict.  There is another application that is using port 50721.
I suggest you could open your task manager and end the IIS express task. Then you could right click the project and click properties, then click the web tag and modify the project url's port to another one.

Comment: As I said, no port works, I tried several ports. Netstat is not giving anything and I spent yesterday 1h shutting down services randomly.

Comment: Try `netstat -ao | findstr <port_number_to_search_for>` to find out which process has used that port.

Comment: Have you tried to delete the .vs folder and reset the port?

Comment: As mentioned I tried all of the things from the other stack questions. How would resetting the port work if as mentioned this persists no matter which port I use.

Answer (score 0):

Try going into the Visual Studio Installer and uninstall-reinstall the ASP.NET dev components. Sometimes you have to start all over again to make dev tools work with updates on client builds.

Comment: problem persists after updating and reinstalling individual components