# IIS application pool started but API not responding

Tags: .net, iis

I have two servers running an API, but on one of them the API is not responding anymore. This happened right after my colleague added *another* API under the same application pool... Since then the API stopped responding and I get a 503 Service Unavailable error, but only on the one server. The other server runs the API without problems.

This is what I tried:

- I first removed the API my colleague added from application pool and restarted the pool, which didn't work
- Recycling the application pool.
- Rebooting the server.
- Changing the Rapid-Fail Protection setting to false.
- Changing the identity from ApplicationPoolIdentity (which it has always used) to LocalService, LocalSystem, NetworkService and back to ApplicationPoolIdentity.
- Creating a new application pool and moving the API to that one. Stop/start/recycle not working here either.

The application pool keeps running when I start it and I see no errors in the event viewer. The code on both servers are the same. I tried connecting to the server with telnet and that worked, so there are no network issues.
I can still access the API throught localhost, but when connecting through the website I get the 503 error.

Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, it could be that the user identity is outdated. Especially, the application pool will stop when the next request arrives. Try to assign a new `user/password` to the application pool identity.
In addition, there are some other reasons that lead to this issue, check this discussion for more details.
[HTTP Error 503, the service is unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322937/http-error-503-the-service-is-unavailable)
https://bobcares.com/blog/iis-http-error-503-the-service-is-unavailable/