# ASP.Net Core API giving a 503 error from SSIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, iis-10

I can't get my IIS site to run and I've tried most of the solutions I've seen.  I started with a clean IIS server for testing this.  If I try to access via the DNS name I get a 503.  If instead I get on the webserver and run `dotnet path\to\app.dll` it starts without issue, and I can then `curl localhost:5000/weatherforecast` and get back the default JSON. So the app itself is clearly fine and working, it's something in the IIS config.  Here's what I did:

1. Installed the .NET Core Hosting Bundle on my Windows Server 2019 system, then rebooted.
2. Ran Computer Management and in System Tools -> Local Users and Group -> Groups I added the domain account to both `Users` and `IIS_IUSRS` groups.
3. In IIS Manager I created a new site and set the binding to my DNS name on port 80.
4. Set the application pool for that new site to `No Managed Code` for the CLR version and set the identity to the domain account.
5. Created a default VS 2019 ASP.NET Core API, set the target framework to .NET 5.0
6. Published, via a Folder Profile, with a target framework of `net5.0` and a runtime of `win-x64`.
7. Restarted the IIS site then went to `http://my.domain.name/weatherforecast` and got a 503.

I'm not even remotely close to being an IIS administrator, so at this point I don't know how to further debug the issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13322937/14874039 This post may help.

Comment: Unfortunately none of those solutions made any difference.

Comment: Does the error message is "Service unavailable"? You can create a new application pool and run again. It is possible that an unknown problem has occurred in the original application pool. In this case, creating a new application pool is the simplest solution.