# Trying to run appsin IIS, they work in iis express, but not in iis, all I get is a http 503 service unavailable

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, iis

Visual Studio, C#, Windows 10, IIS v10.0.14393.0

Trying to run apps in IIS, they work in IIS Express, but not in IIS, all I get is a http 503 service unavailable error.

Most of what I read says the user for the app pool is bad. How do I test that?

I tried creating a new app pool and an new identity and it fails too. My app path currently has permissions for everyone=all (for testing purposes).

This all used to work, but I went down the vue app rabbit hole, and I may have messed something up...

What else can it be?

I uninstalled IIS and WAS, and re-installed them, then set up failed request tracing per the doc linked in the comments, but turning -everything- on...

I created a new empty asp.net mvc web app in vs2017 and ran it, works in iisexpress, changed to iis, hit create a virtual directory, ran, failed, ran with out debugging got the 503 error below.

no files in the logging location (screenshot)

[image]

Screen shot of error
[image]

IIS screen shot
[image]

NO Errors is error event log, just this warning
[image]

Not sure what else I can provide, any hints on where to look or what to provide appreciated.

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322937/http-error-503-the-service-is-unavailable?page=1&tab=modifieddesc#tab-top

Comment: IIS express is not equivalent to iis, do you have a detailed error message? if there is not, try using failed request tracing to see details about 503 error.

Comment: Most of the differences are well known, https://halfblood.pro/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: Only errors is logs or event files are a different app pool getting restarted for inactivity.

Comment: Please post a detailed error message, otherwise it won't solve your problem. If not you can try using failed request tracing: [Using Failed Request Tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules).

Comment: I followed the instructions here, but it doesn't let me choose verbosity or url re-write on the last dialog. Both fields are blank.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, can you explain in detail? or provide a screenshot of the problem encountered.